# JWPlayer HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: http, ssl, https, jwplayer, jwplayer6

I am converting my site from HTTP to HTTPS. All the browser works perfectly like plays videos, shows all contents as expected but IE gives me security alert for viewing blocked content and if I don’t accept this, it doesn't play the video. I want IE also should play the videos without accepting the blocked content alert.

Couple of things I already tried:

- Implemented Cross-Domain XML
- Made all the Player Plugins local copy

But all this attempt didn't work. Can someone help me on this issue please? I am using JWplayer Version 6.

I would appreciate your early response!

Thanks,

Comment: Make sure ALL of the resources on the page are being called with HTTPS. No mixed content.

Comment: Thank Neutron! mixed content was to problem. It is working fine now.

Thanks Again!